# Symfony Admin Generator Doctrine executeCreate

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, admin, symfony-1.4

Thanks for any help with this, I'm very new to the Symfony framework so just trying to get my head around it.

I want to be able to intercept a submitted form from the admin area and modify the data.

Here's what I've got so far (in basic form)..

/apps/backend/modules/proposition/actions/action.class.php

```
class propositionActions extends autoPropositionActions {

  public function executeCreate(sfWebRequest $request) {
    // modify the name
    $name = $request->getParameter('name');
    $name = $name . ' is an idiot';
    $request->setParameter('name', $name);

    return parent::executeCreate($request);
  }

}
```

My form does contain a name field:

/apps/backend/modules/proposition/config/generator.yml

```
generator:
  class: sfDoctrineGenerator
  param:
    model_class:           Proposition
    theme:                 admin
    non_verbose_templates: true
    with_show:             false
    singular:              ~
    plural:                ~
    route_prefix:          proposition
    with_doctrine_route:   true
    actions_base_class:    sfActions

    config:
      actions: ~
      form:
        display: [name, icon, overview, published]
```

I'm not sure if that's the file you need to see of not, but it's definitely in the HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="proposition_name" name="proposition[name]">
```

When I submit the form it just saves my name. I want it to save my name appending ' is an idiot'.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track Peter, but modifying the `$request` too late for it to have any effect.

You could do this sort of modification of inbound data in [the "doClean" part of the Form's validator](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/05-Custom-Widgets-and-Validators).

Or, if you have special processing to do, it might make more sense to override the generated `processForm()` function.  Just copy it out of  `cache/frontend/dev/modules/autoProposition/actions/actions.class.php` into your `apps/backend/modules/proposition/actions/action.class.php` and start hacking.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, processForm() was the function I was looking for. I've extended it and it's now working as I want. I was wondering where the autoPropositionActions class lived, looking at this has given me a lot more to play with :)

Comment: What's the syntax do change the value of a field in processform ? I'm trying to set author_id to the id of the current logged-in user...

Comment: @Manu it looks like you're already getting help on [the question you asked about that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742099/auto-populate-a-field-in-symfony-admin-generator).  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Why do want to do it in your action? I think most suitable place is form itself.

You can modify value of any column by adding update*Column method:

```
class PropositionForm extends BasePropositionForm
{
  public function updateNameColumn($name)
  {
    return $name . ' is an idiot';
  }
}
```

**Note:** If you don't want the " is an idiot" string appended in other places your form is used you can subclass the original form and add your method there (i.e. in AdminPropositionForm).

You can change the form used with admin generated module by overloading getFormClass() method in your module's configuration class (propositionGeneratorConfiguration). It should return the name of form class you want to use.

**Note 2:** You have to accessed form values differently:

```
$proposition = $request->getParameter('proposition', array());
$name = $proposition['name'];
```

Comment: Thanks kuba, your second note helped. Although once I'd extended processForm() I used it like:

$parms = $request->getParameter($form->getName());
$name = $parms['name'];

Comment: @Peter: you're right. Using $form->getName() is better than using the name explicitly.