# Symfony admin generator : add user id before saving

Tags: symfony1, sfdoctrineguard

I'm creating my own blog engine to learn Symfony, and I have a question :

In the generated administration pages for a blog post, I have a drop-down list of authors, to indicate the author_id.

I'd like to hide that drop-down list, and set the author_id to the id of the current logged-in user when the post is created (but not when it is edited)

How can I accomplish that ?

**Edit**
I've tried those :

```
$request->setParameter(sprintf("%s[%s]", $this->form->getName(), "author_id"), $this->getUser()->getAttribute("user_id"));
$request->setParameter("content[author_id]", $this->getUser()->getAttribute("user_id"));
$request->setParameter("author_id", $this->getUser()->getAttribute("user_id"));
$request->setParameter("author_id", 2);
$request->setParameter("content[author_id]", 2);
$request->setParameter("author_id", "2");
$request->setParameter("content[author_id]", "2");
```

In processForm() and executeCreate()

**Resolved !**

The final code is :

```
  public function executeCreate(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $form = $this->configuration->getForm();
    $params = $request->getParameter($form->getName());
    $params["author_id"] = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId();;
    $request->setParameter($form->getName(), $params);

    parent::executeCreate($request);

  }
```

Comment: I can't believe how hard it is to find info on this. Am I the first one to want to save the author of document ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `executeCreate` function in the actions file. When binding post data to the form, merge the current user's id into it.

**2nd update**

I did some experimenting, and this works:

```
class fooActions extends autoFooActions
{
  public function executeCreate(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $form = $this->configuration->getForm();
    $params = $request->getParameter($form->getName());
    $params["author_id"] = 123;
    $request->setParameter($form->getName(), $params);

    parent::executeCreate($request);
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good idea; could you detail it a little more ?

Comment: I'll try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727314/symfony-admin-generator-doctrine-executecreate

Comment: thanks; it still fails to save, saying that author_id is required .. I'll try to make it optional.

Comment: Make sure your form field's value is sent as `formname[author_id]`, that's the default format, so I assumed it in my code.

Comment: It seems that the new executeCreate is not called ... I've added "$i = 3/0;" and it didn't throw an error.

Comment: Create is the action that creates the new object, it should be called. I can't give you tips how to debug this one, never seen it not getting called. Maybe check the form's action attribute to see where it posts the data.

Comment: Nevermind, it is called. It throws an error if I write $this->foo;

Answer (score 0):

change the widget in the form with the sfWidgetFormInputHidden and set the value with sfUser attribute (that defined when a user logged in)

override the executeCreate() and set the author_id widget (thanks to maerlyn :D )

```
public function executeCreate(sfWebRequest $request){
  parent::executeCreate($request);
    $this->form->setWidget('author_id', new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(array(),array('value'=>$this->getUser()->getAttribute('author_id'))) );
}
```

Comment: Using `sfContext::getInstance()` is bad practise. Use dependency injection. Suggested reading: http://webmozarts.com/2009/07/01/why-sfcontextgetinstance-is-bad/

Comment: As Maerlyn suggests using context is a bad practice. Just pass author_id into the form as an option.

Comment: but the rest is valid ? $this->setWidget('author_id', new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(array(),array('value'=>1))) is ok ?

Comment: it is valid, but as mentioned by Maerlyn it's highly not recommended .. :D

Comment: $this->form->setWidget AFTER  parent::executeCreate ??

Comment: Using a hidden input is absolutely unreliable. Your user will be able to post as any other user, not just himself. Also: `parent::executeCreate` will save the object and redirect to the index action, code after that is not executed.

Comment: oo yeah .. i've forgot about the processForm in the parent::executeCreate :D and redirect to the edit action

Answer (score 0):

In Objects , the solution is:   (new and $this)

```
class fooActions extends autoFooActions
{
  public function executeCreate(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->form = new XxxxxForm();
    $params = $request->getParameter($this->form->getName());
    $params["author_id"] = 123;
    $request->setParameter($this->form->getName(), $params);

    parent::executeCreate($request);
  }
}
```